# Finding D.E. for part of an RC Circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

Find the differential equation governing y(t), t>0.

$$u(t) = 2U_0(t)      Amps$$

[image]
.

KVL (clockwise): $$2*I_c + \frac{1}{4} \frac{dV_c}{dt} - y(t)=0$$

$$I_c = 2- \frac{y(t)}{6}$$

I am having a hard time figuring out what my next step should be.

Comment: @Chu U_0(t) is equal to 1 for t>0 and 0 for t<0. A its just for amps.

Comment: The way this is normally done (for a 1st order circuit like this, i.e. having only one capacitor or inductor) is calculate the Thevenin equivalent seen by the capacitor/inductor. Then you have a very easy time applying just what you know for a forced response input to a capacitor. The resistors just see a scaled (and in-phase) version of the capacitor's response, which is easy to derive from the capacitor's response.

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out what you want.
You draw a current source, yet name it's output u(t), which is confusing at best. At worst case I can't even imagine. It might make people think it is a voltage, so y(t) = u(t) and there is no differential equation needed. And what is Uo(t)? It's totally redundant information. You don't even use it in the differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first equation you have shown:
$$2*I_c + \frac{1}{4} \frac{dV_c}{dt} - y(t)=0$$
The first term is Voltage, the second term is Current, the third is Voltage. So the second term cannot be correct, it should simply be the voltage across the capacitor.
$$2*I_c + V_c - y(t)=0$$
There are three dependent variables and you only have two equations. So you need one more equation/relationship. Add the equation that relates current to voltage of a capacitor:
$$I_c =\frac{1}{4} \frac{dV_c}{dt}$$
Now you can take combine the three equations into one equation with a single dependent variable y(t) as requested by your problem statement.